# Ratio of triangle A and B if the length of the sides are A:25,25, 30 and b:25,25, 40

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

If $A$ triangle's side length are $25,25$ and $30$ and $B$ triangle's length are $25,25$ and $40$ what is the ratio between the two areas of the triangles? #math

Comment: Ratio between what?  The triangles are not similar.  Maybe you mean ratio of the areas?  Do you know [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)? There is a *much* easier way.

Comment: "visions of 3-4-5 triangles danced in their heads"

Answer (score 3):

$A$'s side lengths are: $25, 25 \text{, and }30$

Let $S = \dfrac{25+25+30}{2}=40$

Using Heron's Formula we know:
$$Area_A = \sqrt{40(40-25)(40-25)(40-30)}$$
$$=\sqrt{40(15)(15)(10)}$$
$$=\sqrt{90000}$$
$$=300$$

$B$'s side lengths are: $25, 25 \text{, and }40$

Let $S = \dfrac{25+25+40}{2}=45$

Using Heron's Formula we know:
$$Area_B = \sqrt{45(45-25)(45-25)(45-40)}$$
$$ =\sqrt{45(20)(20)(5)}$$
$$=\sqrt{90000}$$
$$=300$$

So $Area_A:Area_B = 1:1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** These two triangles are isosceles, so the altitude on the base bisects the base.

That means the $25-25-30$ triangle is split in to two right triangles with a hypotenuse of $25$ and one leg of $15$. What is the altitude of the $25-25-30$ triangle?

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

The $25-25-40$ triangle is split in to two right triangles with a hypotenuse of $25$ and one leg of $20$. What is the altitude of the $25-25-40$ triangle?